# Spotify keyboard shortcuts - MacOS & Microsoft Sculpt keyboard

Tags: macos, spotify

I recently got an ergonomic Sculpt keyboard that I use with my Macbook. I managed to configure some handy keyboard shortcuts for e.g. moving between screens but I'm failing miserably at configuring "Next" and "Previous" buttons to use with Spotify.

I tried first Karabiner but it's apparently missing both options. So I started digging in keyboard settings. In Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts I'm able to add manually a new shortcut for moving to the next song. And it works but only when I'm on the screen with Spotify. But the whole point of this shortcut is to switch between songs while doing something else, without even looking at Spotify app. And that I cannot configure somehow.

Has anyone done something like this before and can recommend a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Karabiner can easily do this though. Make a complex modification rule

bind some keybind to keybind `fastfoward` to skip next song and `rewind` to go to previous track. `play_or_pause` for obviously playing or pausing.

in fact i made a simple test to see if this works or not

```
    {
      "description": "Spotify next and prev button map",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "n"
          },
          "to": [ {
            "key_code": "fastforward"
          } ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

I make the letter `n` here to be `fastfoward` you can edit as you like